# Youtube feed array items in json showing as NULL

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

I am grabbing the comments from videos, but the "author name" and their id is giving NULL.

This is what I have.

```
$feedUrl='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$selected_video_id.'/comments?v=2&alt=json';  
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($feedUrl),true);
$info = $data["feed"];
$entry = $info["entry"];
$nEntry = count($entry);

for($i=0;$i<$nEntry;$i++){ 
    $name =  $entry[$i]['author']['name']['$t'];
    $userId = $entry[$i]['author']['yt$userId']['$t'];
    $content = $entry[$i]['content']['$t'];
    $published_2 = $entry[$i]['published']['$t'];
}
```

Content and Published are collected fine, but the name and userID are not.

The feed does have the elements in it as have looked at it in the youtube data api demo beta. As well as it shows everything if you do a feed request in the browser.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments
```

So am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$name =  $entry[$i]['author'][0]['name']['$t'];
$userId = $entry[$i]['author'][0]['yt$userId']['$t'];
$content = $entry[$i]['content']['$t'];
$published_2 = $entry[$i]['published']['$t'];
```

Or better yet:

```
$feedUrl=file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ASO_zypdnsQ/comments?v=2&alt=json'); 
$json = json_decode($feedUrl, true);
foreach($json['feed']['entry'] as $entry) {
    echo $entry['author'][0]['name']['$t']."<br>";
    echo $entry['author'][0]['yt$userId']['$t']."<br>";
    echo $entry['content']['$t']."<br>";
    echo $entry['published']['$t']."<br>";
}
```

You can use `foreach` like the above :)

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks. 
By the way.... Why is the [0] needed in-between when it is not on other items that are nested ?! ( above examples aside)

Comment: Apparently youtube allows, or has some sort of availability where each comment has multiple authors. No idea why!